# Find the lapse of time

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the time lapse between 2 diferent hours....

```
function time()
    {
        var startime=(document.getElementById("horaentrada").value);
        var endtime=(document.getElementById("horasaida").value);

        document.getElementById("total_horas").value = (endtime-startime);
    }
```

the idea is to fill a html input "total_horas" with the result. The function is triggered by an onchange event. The entry format is "HH:mm:ss", by instance 9:35:22.

I've tried a lot of things, but, no one works I get NaN.

Comment: What is your actual question? Does the code you posted work or not? Are you getting errors? How does your page behave differently than you expect?

Comment: it dosen't display a result, only "NaN"...in the html input

Comment: What kind of example values are you using?

Comment: You can't just subtract two strings like `09:35:00`, subtraction works with *numbers* like `4.3923` or `94`, not with strings like `"09:35:00"`.

Comment: So I must convert the string to numbers, then make the calculartion an in the end converto to string again?

Comment: Yes, but consider using `moment.js` instead of attempting the conversion by hand.

Comment: I'm already discovering the moment.js...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function time()
    {
        var startime=(document.getElementById("horaentrada").value);
        var endtime=(document.getElementById("horasaida").value);

        document.getElementById("total_horas").value= (parseFloat(endtime,10)-parseFloat(startime, 10));
    }
```

Also, make sure to run the function after the dom is loaded.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LnLdB/2/ . Just be gentle with the stuff you input in the boxes.

EDIT: Here is an updated fiddle, using moment.js. It subtracts hours in the format "HH:mm:ss": http://jsfiddle.net/LnLdB/13/

Comment: This won't help. He's probably not entering "9.75" hours, which is the only scenario where `parseFloat` is a valid suggestion. Either he's entering "9" hours, in which case there's no problem with subtraction (`"9" - "7" == 2` works fine) or he might be enter `"9:45"` in which case `parseFloat` is totally wrong.

Comment: the values are something like 09:35:00

Comment: Yes, but at least if both boxes are filled in, he will no longer get NaN

Comment: @malaquias Oh, ok then you should use something like moment.js to parse the dates, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @meagar Wrong assumption then. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer, I think this should be ok.

Comment: @malaquias jsfiddle appears to be down entirely, try again later and let me know if it still doesn't work

Comment: I will upvote the answer if you change it to the correct answer (the one in the second JSFiddle).